Href don't work in WebView that's set with a onTouchlistener()
Href doesn't work in a WebView where onTouchlistener() is set
Listed is my onCreate & onTouchEvent functions, and the string that's launched in the WebView.
The swipe & scroll work just fine, but Hrefs don't work at all.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<![CDATA[<h4>About Scriptor</h4> <br><br>The <b>It’s a fun and simple step to begin writing your full screenplay using <a href="http://www.finaldraft.com/">Final Draft</a>, or other film-script formatting software. <br><br>Even more of Syd Field\’s screenwriting teachings are available in the 3-Book E- Bundle, <a href="https://safe.com/yxrrx3a6/">\“The Essential Screenplay.\”</a> <br><br>]]>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 

binding = ActivityDataOrgBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
val view = binding.root 
setContentView(view) 

var webView = binding.dataHolderText
binding.dataHolderText.setOnTouchListener { v: View, m: MotionEvent -> onTouchEvent(m) true} 

dataText = getString(R.string.help_about)
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, dataText, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
}


override fun onTouchEvent(tochevent: MotionEvent): Boolean { when (tochevent.action) { 
  //action == 0 
  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> { 
    x1 = tochevent.x 
    y1 = tochevent.y 
    return true } 

// action == 2 
   MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> { 
    swipeLeft(tochevent) } 

// action == 1 
  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> { 
    swipeLeft(tochevent) } 

// action == 3 
  MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> { 
    swipeLeft(tochevent) } 

// all other movements 
  else -\> 
    super.onTouchEvent(tochevent) } 

//lets it do what it normally does
return super.onTouchEvent(tochevent) }


private fun swipeLeft(event: MotionEvent) {
  x2 = event.x
  y2 = event.y
  if (abs(x2 - x1) > MIN_DISTANCE && abs((y1 - y2)) < MIN_DISTANCE) {
    onBackPressed()}
}

